# How to list all URLs in the source code files of a website with command line tools?

Tags: security, tools

I have folder that contains the source code files of a website (tons of html, css and php files). I would like to find an automatic method (preferably with command line tools) to scan this folder recursively and get a list of URLs that are included in these files.

I guess it's possible with *find* and *grep* and some *regular expressions*, but my knowledge is limited about combining these commands.

Basically it'd be a good way to find out if there are any "hidden" URL calls (data leaks, backdoors or secret download functions) in the code of the CME or installed plug-ins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grep command and search recursively for `http` in a documment.

## Syntax

(If I can remember well)

```
grep -r http ./var/html/index.php
```

Where `grep -r` will force a recursive search, altought you can use other methods too, type `grep --help` to see them.
`http` is the string you are searching for, and `/var/html/index.php` is the directory where the file is located.

Comment: Thank you.
Just to avoid confusion about folder naming...
grep -r MySearchedString ./MyFolder

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ can accomplish this job with one button press: search for `http` in given folder including subfolder, and Notepad++ creates a list of all findings.

Surely there are many methods to do this, which are more and much more byzantine as this one.

Comment: Thank you, Evgeniy. I think your idea is good and I marked it as useful. However I use Linux and that's why I am interested in some geeky command line solutions too. You know, native command line tools are faster than Notepad++ on Wine.

Comment: i'm pretty sure, that any text editor, which is natively working on Linux has same function, so you don't need to run Wine.

Comment: Sure, you are right! Maybe I will wait for a few hours for an answer... and if I get none, I will turn it into an Emacs question. I'm 100% sure there is a crazy keyboard shortcut for this in Emacs. :)